# Native function no implementation found

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Problem: 20% of users are receiving:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
No implementation found for java.lang.String com.example.utils.API.getHashString(android.content.Context) (tried Java_com_example_utils_API_getHashString and Java_com_example_utils_API_getHashString__Landroid_content_Context_2)
```

For other 80% app working perfectly, no exception on my test devices as well.
Can't figure out what's the problem.

**EDIT1**:
Library loads perfectly on splash screen. No exception on that point.

```
static { System.loadLibrary("my-lib"); }
```

**EDIT2**:
Just reproduced the error. It is absolutely random. App function call works fine, and at some time it starts failing. The only fix is re-installing the app.

Comment: Try to call the problematic method from the static constructor. Does it fail on same devices?

Comment: Do you mean static block? I'd like to try, but I can't test all solutions in production on real users.

Comment: You mean, this problem has never reproduced in the lab? And your logs show that the same devices work OK for other users?

Comment: I receiving crash logs from Fabric crashlytics. What do you mean by "Lab"? Amazon Test Farm?

Comment: By Lab, I mean a device on which you can install a debug version of your app.

Comment: Maybe you can use https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/ - their free tier may be enough to give you the necessary input.

Comment: Unanswerable. You need to show (1) your Java class with the `native` method declaration (2) your `.h` file generated by `javah` and (3) your `.c` file whose declaration of the native method agrees with (2). If you don't have all three of these, there's your answer.

Comment: @EJP then why 80% of users are not affected by issue if something wrong in my declarations.

Comment: Looks like you are using native code and that correspond to a library. Have you compiled this for all platforms? Like arm64, armv7, mips, intel etc. may be the 20% users fall in unsupported platforms

Comment: @manishg Compiled for all platforms, Ill add another edit to question with fresh info.

Comment: Do you have any statistics related to the OS version on which your users getting this error?

Comment: @j2ko  62% - Android 6, 33% - Android 4, 5% - Android 5.
50% of them - samsung.

Comment: In your edit you mentioned you were able to reproduce this problem and it was random? Does this mean on the same device it works most of the time and occasionally it fails?

Comment: @manishg yes, on samsung A3, and I could not find any clues why crash happend.

Comment: Where is the `static {...}` block located? A possible reason for this could be that the code is not executed before some calls.

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana On splash screen, and I guess this is it.  Ill check that moment.

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana please post your advice as answer and I ll give bounty to you, thanks again.

Comment: @StanislavParkhomenko I repeat. Unanswerable. You need to show (1) your Java class with the native method declaration (2) your .h file generated by `javah` and (3) your .c file whose declaration of the native method agrees with (2). If you don't have all three of these, there's your answer. If you can't figure it out for yourself, post all that stuff here. Until then: unanswerable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following my comment and later comments from @stanislav-parkhomenko, I'm reposting it as an answer. Thanks!

My comment:

> Where is the static {...} block located? A possible reason for this could be that the code is not executed before some calls.

And later confirmed by himself that this was the cause:

> The problem was in library initialization. Splash screen run not always, because of sharing functionality, thats why some times library did not load.
>
> Thanks to Xavier Rubio Jansana for advice, which cured my blindness.

Glad it helped!

Comment: My app runs fine without proguard enabled but after enabling proguard I am getting the same error. I have been stuck here for days and I don't want to disable proguard for release. What can be the possible way out for this?

Comment: @bhaskar If it fails only when enabling Proguard, I'm pretty sure is not the same problem. You should create a new question in SO with as much information as posible.

Comment: For anyone reaching this comment, the related question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56948049/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-implementation-found-for-java-lang-string-whe/).

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by method signature mismatch between Java and native library you are loading. It is likely that 20% of users have different version of library file with same name. If it is your own library try giving it relatively unique name and load it from absolute path to reduce chance of name conflict.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's trying to load a native library, and there isn't support in Android `Gradle` for native code yet. You should double-check the docs for your library to confirm; I tried to look it up but it looks like it's a commercial library without publicly accessible docs.

You could just put the `.so` files into `jniLibs` folder in `src/main`. This was introduced in AS 0.7.2

As a sample, see [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-gradle) from [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), or see [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) page for official samples (scroll to the bottom of page)

Yes Still no support for native library in Android gradle.Just I followed simple hack.It works great.[Check this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/nQobKd2Gl_8/Z5yWAvCh4h4J)

Comment: nope, it is my own library which contains only few function implementations for java.