# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String when proguard enabled

Tags: java, android, c++

I am getting the following error when I enable proguard.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.osolutions.otv.utilities.al.b() (tried Java_com_osolutions_otv_utilities_al_b and Java_com_osolutions_otv_utilities_al_b__)
   at com.osolutions.otv.utilities.al.b(Native Method)
   at com.osolutions.otv.utilities.al.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
   at com.osolutions.otv.activity.SplashScreenActivity.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.osolutions.otv.activity.y.run(Unknown Source)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I have initialized the Cpp class also using

```
static {
     System.loadLibrary("baseUrl");
}
```

If I disable proguard it works fine. This is the case when proguard is enabled.

Comment: Presumably the real name of your method was not "com.osolutions.otv.utilities.al.b"?

Comment: [This bit](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples#native) in the ProGuard manual seems relevant.

Comment: @Botje that's because proguard has been enabled

Comment: Yes, that was not clear from your question. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @Botje please see my answer, especially the last sentence :)

Comment: Eh, I assumed they tried what was in the link and could not get it to work. You deserve the credit for typing out what the magic ProGuard incantation actually did.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Botje suggests, it looks like the problem in your case is that the native name and the definition of your method in Java side get out of sync, so to speak.

Your `public native String myMethod();` gets changed to `public native String b();` by ProGuard, but your native implementation keeps the original name. That's why the Java runtime cannot find it.

You need to add the following to your ProGuard file:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

Please, do NOT mark this answer as the solution, as it was @Botje who came with it (I just developed the explanation a little further).

@Botje please add your own answer so he can mark it as the solution.

Comment: Had a similar problem with another project and this fixed it! Thanks so much